# URL to redirect related model instance django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have a 2 models with ForeignKey linked to each other

```
class Moc(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
  scope = models.TextField(max_length=128, blank=False)
  ....
  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Verifier(models.Model):
  moc = models.ForeignKey(Moc, related_name='verifiers' on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  approve = models.BooleanField(default=False). reject = 
  reject = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  ....
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

I have a respective forms, views and templates to create, update, delete records.

```
def verifier_signoff_view(request, pk):

    verifier = Verifier.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = VerifierSignForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VerifierSignForm(request.POST, instance=verifier)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            if verifier.approve is True and verifier.reject is True:
                return HttpResponseForbidden('You have either APPROVE or REJECT - operation not allowed!')
            else:
                form.save()

        return redirect('verify_coorinate' pk=verifier.moc_id) # This is where I need help...
    else:
        return render(request, 'moc/verify_signoff.html', context={'verifier': verifier, 'form': form})
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
....
....

path('moc-content/<int:pk>/verify-coordinate, views.verify_coordinate_view', name='verifiy_coordinate'),
....
....
]
```

What I want is that after I update verifier instance as per above view, I want to redirect back to moc instance rather than verifier instance, i.e. pass in url Moc instance pk instead of Verifier instance pk.

Any help please...

Comment: please provide us an url with namespace 'verify_coorinate'

Comment: Can you include urls.py?

Comment: I have added url.py for verify_coordinate_view  and bit clarified my question at the end. I want to pass moc model instance pk (I am trying to do it by verifier.moc_id

Comment: @MaximDanilov can you check-out please?

Comment: @haduki, can you look to it please?

Answer (score 1):

you probably forgot the comma:

```
redirect('verify_coorinate', pk=verifier.moc_id) # This is line, where you need help
```

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Please, try to use Django-GCBV. In your case it can be UpdateView or FormView with SingleObjectMixin
more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

Comment: Thanks for your time Maxim, I have figured out that I had a typo in my namespace in Views (verifie_coorinator instead of verifier_coordinator), I have fixed it and all works fine now.